# Win32 C++ Resource Dialogs Change Fonts Within

Tags: c++, file, resources

I have a simple question, I couldn't find a thing on google. Basically I want to use multiple fonts within a dialog setup in the resource file.

The font specified being default, but I am wanting to, for example, use a different font on a/ the push button.

I'm not sure if it is possible. Here is how I have it setup.

```
IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 165, 250
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Options"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    GROUPBOX        "Target",IDC_STATIC,7,7,155,35
        PUSHBUTTON      "TRGT1",IDC_TARGET1,15,18,30,14

    PUSHBUTTON      "&Damage Click",IDC_DMGCLICK,7,60,84,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_INPUTCLICKCOUNT, 7, 80, 84, 14
END
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you're asking (though I'd love to proved wrong!) but you can always change the font of your button by sending it a `WM_SETFONT` message from with your `WM_INITDIALOG` handler.

Comment: I am kind of new at the Win32 stuff.

I looked up the WM_SETFONT message on MSDN and from what I saw, I couldn't figure out how it works. I can create a handle for a font, but then what do I do? I have a resource ID for the control, and can create a font.

Thanks.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: Something like `SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BUTTON), WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hFont, 0);` in your WM_INITDIALOG handler (and if you don't know what that is, you need to go back and do some more reading!)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.

One last question. I create the font in the WM_INITDIALOG and I don't keep track of the handle. I am wondering if I need to use DeleteObject() on it when the dialog closes.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: Yes, that's right. Store the HFONT somewhere and call `DeleteObject` on it when the dialog goes away, usually via `WM_DESTROY`.